# How to set font " Balzano" to the text in enclosed in <p></p> on my website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I want to set font "Balzano" to the following text enclosed in

by means of inline css. How to achieve it?

```
<p>Nice Site</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS property `font-family`:

```
<p style="font-family:Balzano;">Nice Site</p>
```

To make it work on machines that do not have that font installed, you need to make a web version available.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to create instance for "Balzano" font in your css file.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Balzano';
  src: url('Balzano.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('Balzano.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('Balzano.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('Balzano.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('Balzano.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Now you can call the same form your HTML code as inline css.

```
<p style="font-family: "Balzano", Times, serif;">Nice Site</p>
```

Comment: This postulates that the font may be so used, which is probably not true: Balzano® is not licensed for web use.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the info. I have given the solution keeping web fonts in mind.